# Shell: redirect stdout to /dev/null and stderr to stdout

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I saw this interesting question at a comment on [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-redirect-output-and-errors-to-devnull/).

That I found I even can't find a flexible way to do this in one-line command with sh.

As far my thought for the solution is:

```
tmp_file=`mktemp`
(./script 2>$tmp_file >/dev/null; cat $tmp_file) | ./other-script
rm tmp_file
```

But you see, this is not synchronous, and fatally, it's so ugly.

Welcome to share you mind about this. :)

Comment: Did you try `./script.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null` ?

Comment: @cnicutar It seemed I have a wrong understanding in the start. I supposed `2>&1` will redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and the `1>/dev/null` will then redirect both them into `/dev/null`. Well I need to relearn some shell.

Comment: In my case, the `2>&1` needed to go at the end, eg: `if ping -c 1 fake.x > /dev/null 2>&1;then echo true;else echo false;fi`

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You want

```
./script 2>&1 1>/dev/null | ./other-script
```

The order here is important. Let's assume stdin (fd 0), stdout (fd 1) and stderr (fd 2) are all connected to a tty initially, so

```
0: /dev/tty, 1: /dev/tty, 2: /dev/tty
```

The first thing that gets set up is the pipe. other-script's stdin gets connected to the pipe, and script's stdout gets connected to the pipe, so script's file descriptors so far look like:

```
0: /dev/tty, 1: pipe, 2: /dev/tty
```

Next, the redirections occur, from left to right. `2>&1` makes fd 2 go wherever fd 1 is currently going, which is the pipe.

```
0: /dev/tty, 1: pipe, 2: pipe
```

Lastly, `1>/dev/null` redirects fd1 to `/dev/null`

```
0: /dev/tty, 1: /dev/null, 2: pipe
```

End result, script's stdout is silenced, and its stderr is sent through the pipe, which ends up in other-script's stdin.

Also see http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/howto/redirection_tutorial

Also note that `1>/dev/null` is synonymous to, but more explicit than `>/dev/null`

Comment: In my edit comment I incorrectly referenced stdin instead of stdout though the edit itself is still correct.
I could not see how to fix edit comment or comment on edit review so mentioning here.

Comment: @geirha Excellent. What if we have to output to >/dev/null, and stderr both to a file and screen? Thanks

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy To output both to terminal and a file, use the `tee` command. `./script 2>&1 >/dev/null | tee file`

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work in zsh. It ends up redirecting script's stdout and stderr to the pipe. Is this a bug or a feature, I'm wondering.

Comment: I want to log the timestamp only when my internet connection is interrupted.
The below command is working as expected.

`ping www.google.com 2>&1 1>/dev/null | perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_'`

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

```
./script 3>&1 1>/dev/null 2>&3 | ./other-script
```

The idea is to "backup" stdout descriptor, close the original stdout and then redirect strerr to saved stdout.

Its much similar to the solution provided by geirha, but its more explicit (bash coding can easily become very obscured).

Answer (score -6):

Well, that's because you can't.  STDOUT and STDERR are just two files, represented by file descriptors, which are just integers, specifically 1 and 2.

What you're asking is to set descriptor 2 to `/dev/null`, then set descriptor 3 to the same file descriptor 2 and have that output go somewhere else.